# OnDestroyView and OnResume not called after replacing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction, fragment-lifecycle

I am trying to replace fragment B with fragment A. But after replacing, `onResume()` is never called on Fragment B, though I can interact with it. Also, `onDestroyView` is never called on Fragment B.

```
val transform = MaterialContainerTransform()
            transform.duration = 500
            val frag = SecondFragment()
            frag.sharedElementEnterTransition = transform


            ( requireActivity() as MainActivityffff).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .addSharedElement(textview_first123123 as ConstraintLayout,"textOCHEK")
                .replace(R.id.frags,frag,"second").addToBackStack("second").commit()
```

The problem I am facing is that I can't reverse my Material transformation back.

If anyone knows how to resolve this issue please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UPD. Found answer: to fix Fragments unexpected behavior I added this dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
```